# Retry Pattern via polly

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, polly, retry-logic

Please let me know is there any chance in the below code the "response" turns to be null, that results an error if I try to get response.result and response.statuscode value in onRetry block.

Sample code below

```
AsyncRetryPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> retryPolicyPost = Policy
    .Handle<HttpRequestException>()
    .OrResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => r != null && (!r.IsSuccessStatusCode))
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(3, times => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(times * 30000),
        onRetry: (response, delay, retryCount, context) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(retryCount);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Result);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Result.StatusCode);
        });
```

I appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there any chance in the below code the "response" turns to be null

Your `response` parameter's type is `DelegateResult<HttpResponseMessage>`, which **can't** be `null` inside the `onRetry` delegate.

BUT the `response.Result` **can** be null! The `DelegateResult` defines two properties which are [mutually exclusive](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/174cc53e17bf02da5e1f2c0d74dffb4f23aa99c0/src/Polly/DelegateResult.cs): `Exception`, `Result`.

So, if the retry logic is triggered because an `HttpRequestException` was thrown then `response.Result` will be `null`, but the `result.Exception` will be an `HttpRequestException`.

If the retry logic is triggered because the `HttpResponseMessage`'s `StatusCode` is different than 200 then `response.Result` will be an `HttpResponseMessage`, but the `result.Exception` will be `null`.

---

This this piece of code is error-prone, it might throw NRE:

```
Console.WriteLine(response.Result.StatusCode);
```

To fix this you can do the following:

```
var statusCode = response.Result?.StatusCode ?? ((HttpRequestException)response.Exception).StatusCode;
Console.WriteLine(statusCode);
```

Please note that [`HttpRequestException`'s `StatusCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httprequestexception.statuscode?view=net-7.0) returns with an `HttpStatusCode?`.